# How to edit a database row value from a html table

Tags: php, sql, forms, button, mysqli

so i have a form with like 6 fields(FirstName,LastName,etc),when the users submit the form,the values are saved in a database.In another page i have a table which shows those values from database,with same 6 cols + another one which contains 2 buttons(delete and edit),the delete one works perfect,but the edit buttons has some issues

The buttons code is this:

```
echo '<td>';
echo '<button><a href="edit.php?idang='.$rand['id'].'">Modifica!</a></button>';
echo '<button><a href="delete.php?idang='.$rand['id'].'">Sterge!</a></button>';
echo '</td>';
```

As you can see i have assigned rand id(this is the primary key for databse rows) to the var idang.

```
$idang=$_GET['idang'];
if(isset($idang)) {
$CerereSQL="SELECT * FROM `angajati` WHERE id='$idang'";
$rezultat=mysqli_query($con,$CerereSQL);
$rand=mysqli_fetch_assoc($rezultat);
```

I've made another variable with the global var $_GET['idang'],and then i have SELECTED the table angajati from database where the primary key from my db its equal with the primary key from the table row,which i've pushed the edit button.This method works for the delete button,and probably for the edit one too,but the real problem is that when i want to edit that row,it will link me to another page containing another form,with original values in the fields,and when i modify those fields with other values,it must change only that row,not the entire table,or the column.But i have no idea how to do that,except that it can be done with the UPDATE statement

The rest of the code,containing the form is:

```
echo '<table border=0 align=center cellspacing=10>';    
echo '<form action="" method=post>';

echo '<tr>';
    echo '<th>Nume:</th><td><input type="text" name=nume value="';

        echo $num;
    echo '"></td>';

    echo '<td style=color:red>';
    echo $err_nume;
    echo $err_nume1;
    echo '</td>';   
echo '</tr>';

echo '<tr>';
    echo '<th>Prenume:</th><td><input type="text" name=prenume value="';
     for($value=1;$value<count($nume);$value++) {
              $c=$c."".$nume[$value];          
           }  
    echo $c;
    echo '"></td>';
    echo '<td style=color:red>';
    echo $err_prenume;
    echo $err_prenume1;
    echo '</td>';
echo '</tr>';

echo '<tr>';
    echo '<th>CNP:</th><td><input type="text" name=cnp value="';
    echo $cnp;
    echo '"></td>';
    echo '<td style=color:red>';
    echo $err_cnp;
    echo $err_cnp1;
    echo $err_cnp2;
    echo '</td>';
echo '</tr>';

echo '<tr>';
    echo '<th>Data angajare:</th><td><input type="text" name=data value="';
    echo $rand['data'];
    echo '"></td>';
    echo '<td style=color:red>';
    echo $err_data;
    echo '</td>';
echo '</tr>';

$companii=array("S.C. 2K Telecom S.R.L.", "S.C. Accessnet International S.R.L.", "S.C. Ad Net Market Media S.A.", "S.C. Idilis S.R.L.", "S.C. Infratel Net S.R.L.");
echo '<tr>';
    echo '<th>Compania:</th>';
    echo '<td>';
    echo '<select name=companie>';
    //echo '<option value="alege">Alege compania</option>';
    //if(!isset($_POST['companie'])){
        echo '<option value='.$companie.'>'.$companie.'</option>';
        $key=array_search($companie, $companii);
        unset($companii[$key]);
    //}
    foreach($companii as $firme) {

echo '<option value="'.$rand['companie'].'"';
if(isset($_POST['companie']) && $_POST['companie'] == $firme) {echo " selected";}
echo ">$firme</option>";
       }   
echo '</select>';   
echo '</td>';   
echo '<td style=color:red>';
echo $err_companie;
echo '</td>';
echo '</tr>';
echo '<tr>';
echo '<th>Functia:</th><td><input type="text" name=functie value="';
echo $rand['functie'];
echo '"></td>';
echo '<td style=color:red>';
echo $err_functie;
echo '</td>';
echo '</tr>';
echo '<tr>';
echo '<td  align=center><a href=tabel.php><input type=button name=button value=Inapoi!></a></td>';
echo '<td  align=center><input type=submit name=submit value=Introducere! ></td>';
echo '<td  align=center><input type=reset name=reset value=Resetare! ></td>';
echo '</tr>';
echo '<tr>';
echo '<td colspan="2" align=center>'.$up.'</td>';
echo '</tr>';
echo '</form>';
echo '</table>';
```

So this form contains the old values from the table row i've pressed the button,and i want to cahnge with new values.Any idea?

Comment: get postdata and run update query with new data on row id

Comment: can you show me with some codes please? I just learned php and few sql things,so i need you to be more specific...

Comment: do you know exactly the update query ?

Comment: $SQL=UPDATE table_name
SET column1=value1,column2=value2,...
WHERE some_column=some_value; right? and then $rezultat=mysqli_query($con,SQL);

Comment: great! so get postdata onclick on Introduce button and apply this query

Comment: check my answer to get idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is basic example to update `name` column of your table. Get other fields and add in the query.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    //echo "<pre>";print_r($_POST);exit; // to check your post data
    $name = $_POST['nume'];

    $query = "UPDATE table_name set name='$name' where id=$idang";
    mysqli_query($query); //run the query    

}
```

Comment: but this is just for 1 col,i need to update the entire row(containing 6 cols)

Comment: yes, i am giving you basic idea to update...get other fields and change in update query.

Comment: Thank you,it worked perfectly.I would vote up your answer but i need 15 rep to do it....sorry

Answer (score 0):

```
echo '<form action="abc.php" method=post>';   // add action
```

abc.php

```
If($_POST)
{
// fetch values from post 
// update query
}
```

in else you can do if $_GET then insert.

I think from this you will get an idea to solve.